# How do I move a Filtered Data Extension automation based off a Synchronized DE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-synchronization

So, I've created several Data Filters off our Data Extension for the purposes of segmenting our audience. I've been manually refreshing these filtered DE's whenever sending, but I'll need to automate the refreshes to make it easier on our team sending out.

Here's my problem: When I create a Filter Activity in Automation Studio for these Data Filters, it saves the resulting Data Extension into the Synchronized Data Extension folder...and I can't move it to the main MarketingCloud DE folders. That's no good. We don't want to muddy our Synchronized DE folder with all these segments.

How can I create segments of our users and automatically refresh them in a cohesive fashion that's in respective folders and relatively turn-key?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're creating the filters off the Synchronized Data Extensions?

When you create the Filter Interaction, it does indeed create the resulting data extension under the same folder as the root, and as you discover you are then restricted in moving it from Synchronised Data Extensions.

I personally find SQL as my preferred approach to segmenting / filtering when it's an automations and Journeys. SQL performance is also more optimal than a Filter. You can also structure how you want your output location and data extension structure.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in Contact Builder. Go to the Data Extensions tab, then you will select the Synchronized Data Extensions folder. Once you select the DE, you can change the location. This does not seem to work in Email Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree. Another possibility is to create one Standard Data Extension per Synchronized Data Extension (using SQL) and then work with them as usual to create filters or whatever.